# IE10 not Passing Parameters to a Web Service Method in an AJAX Post Request

Tags: ajax, web-services, jquery, internet-explorer-10

I have a JQuery function that does an AJAX Post on a web service method. This function works well in FireFox, Chrome, Safari and IE 9 and lower. For some strange reason, IE10 does not pass the parameters needed to execute the web method and throws the following exception:

===========================================================================

ExceptionType=System.InvalidOperationException

Message=Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'parameterX'.

StackTrace=   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)

===========================================================================

I've tried to use all sorts of combinations of passing the data in the AJAX request including the JSON.stringify() method. None worked and this seems like a bug in IE10.

Here is the JQuery function:

```
    var valueX = $inputBox.val().replace("'", "!");
    var valueY = 1;

    myNameSpace.activeAjaxRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: webServiceMethodUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({ parameterX: valueX, parameterY: valueY }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
           // some code here
        }
        ,
        error: function (sender, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           // some code here
        }
    });
```

**Any fix or workaround is highly appreciated!**

Comment: What does the `JSON.stringify` method return on IE10?

Comment: Show us where you're setting `valueX` and `valueY`.

Comment: @CoolGadgetsForGeeks, it returns:

{"parameterX":"cre","parameterY":1}

Comment: @MelanciaUK, I've modified the code block. Please see the top of the block

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235613/jquery-ajax-post-not-working-ie10/14069153#14069153